# What is the IC used for 19-cell LiFePo4 BMS design?

Tags: bms, lifepo4

I am trying to design a BMS for 19-cell (19S7P) LFP battery pack, for one of the two wheeler scooter application. I can see that, there are many IC chips including MPF42790, MPF42791 etc are available with user guides and Evaluation kits. When I skim through it, I did see that, it can be possible to design a BMS for our application with the given documentation and resources.

However, all these kits and parts are constrained to up to 16 cell BMS and I couldn’t find much information on 19 cell BMS design guidelines and part numbers.

I am sure, I could be wrong or missing something here. Your help is much appreciated in this regard. I am happy to have your suggestions for any other company components and resources, that can help me to design 19 cell LFP BMS with following features:

i.  Protection circuits (Voltage, current and temperature protection)

ii. Passive cell balancing

iii. Charging voltage: 77.2V (Max.)

iv. Max. continuous charging current: 20 A

v.  Max. continuous discharge current: 40 A

vi. Open wire detection

vii.    Configurable to NMC and LFP cells

Once again, your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Divide the battery into 10 and 9 cells.

Answer (score 1):

There are no ICs for 19 cells in series because the IC technology does not support such high voltage. Even ICs for 16 cells in series stretch the limits of the IC technology.

Instead, we stack ICs for fewer cells. Looks for stackable Li-ion front end ICs from companies such as TI and LT (now Analog Devices). There are some nice ICs for 6 and 12 cells in series.

Comment: Thank you Davide, I see your point, but, I couldn't find a good source or schematic on stackable design. If have known any user guide for the stackable design, please let me know. It would help me a lot. Appreciate it. Meanwhile, I would definitely, look into the TI and LT ICs for stackable design.

Comment: @ADB: I have a list of Li-ion BMS ICs: http://liionbms.com/php/bms_chips_options.php But it's dated.

Comment: Thank you Davide..The provided table helps in giving me a better idea on how multi cell system work.